# How to know DOM rendering is completed in AngularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to raise an alert or message when my html dom has completed rendering using angularjs with the multiple ng-repeat.

**HTML Code:**

```
       <body>
            <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
               <div ng-repeat="thing in things" my-post-repeat-directive>                                    
                        thing {{thing}}
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="complete">Complete {{complete}}</div>
            </div>
      </body>
```

**JS Code**

```
       function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.complete = false;
          $scope.doComplete = function() {
              $scope.complete = true;
           }

         $scope.things = [
                    'A', 'B', 'C'
                    ];
              }

          angular.module('myApp', [])
          .directive('myPostRepeatDirective', function() {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
           if (scope.$last) {
            scope.$eval('doComplete()');
              }
         };
     });
```

Comment: you should investigate more into https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component rather than controllers

Comment: I think this can be done with bulk loading by using a directive with `scope.$evalAsync()`.  Here is more about it: [How scope evalAsync affects performance](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2635-looking-at-how-scope-evalasync-affects-performance-in-angularjs-directives.htm). But keep in mind, it it evaluates expression _before_ any **DOM rendering** is done and _after_ a **digest cycle** is finished

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has *LIFECYCLE HOOKS* as

```
$postLink(() => {
   yours alert
})
```

> $postLink() - Called after this controller's element and its children
>   have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be
>   used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation